# Is DFS Namespace a Windows service and if so, what is the service name for DFS Namespace?

Tags: windows, services

I want to know the service name for `DFS Namespace`, but I can not find any results when searching for it. The closest I got was [here](http://batcmd.com/windows/10/services/dfsc/), which informs that the service name for `DFS Namespace Client Driver` is `Dfsc`. Is `DFS Namespace Client Driver` the same as `DFS Namespace`? Is there actually a service called `DFS Namespace`?

Additionally, I found two services called `DFS Replication` and `DFS Management Tools`, but I also can not find their service names. What are their service names?

Comment: DFS is part of the windows domain and does not come with a service specifically for that. It it part of the domain services on your domain controller. DFS replication uses DFS to replicate files and folders between servers but not the DFS service itself.